# cannot modify keras layer dropout parameter prior to backend function evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have trained a network model using keras which includes multiple dropout layers.  I have also implemented a stochastic predictor function (using the keras backend) which allows me to get predictions with dropout turned "on."

```
    import keras.backend as K
    F = K.function([model.layers[0].input, K.learning_phase()], [m.layers[-1].output])
```

I call the function using

```
    output = F([x_test[0:1], 1])
```

where x_test is a sample input.

Currently, the dropout rate used in this predictor function is the same as the dropout rate used for training.  **I would like to set a different dropout rate without retraining the network.**

I wrote a script to change all dropout layer rates:

```
    for layer in [l for l in m.layers if "dropout" in np.str.lower(l.name)]:
        layer.rate = 0.5
```

However, when I call my custom function, it does not change the output.  For example, if my trained network uses a rate of 0 (or K.epsilon()), then repeated function calls will yield the same result.  Changing the dropout to 0.5 should yield unique results on each function call.  Yet, this is not the case.  Changing the dropout has no effect.

What *does* work is extracting a single layer, changing the rate, and calling that single layer:

```
    L = my_net.model.layers[0]
    L.rate = 0.5
    L_out1 = K.eval(L.call(x_test[0], training=True))
    L.rate = K.epsilon()
    L_out2 = K.eval(L.call(x_test[0], training=True))
```

Here, L_out1 and L_out2 are unique.  I don't know how to implement this functionality across the whole network.

What is it about the backend function that prevents my model changes from being effective?

Comment: In my experience, manually changing the hyperparameters of a layer does not affect the model unless you reconstruct it after the change.